# Why Does this DataFrame Modification within Function Change Global Outside Function?

Tags: python, pandas, global, local

Why does the function below change the global `DataFrame` named `df`? Shouldn't it just change a local `df` within the function, but not the global `df`?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def adding_var_inside_function(df):
    df['value'] = 0

print(df.columns) # Index([], dtype='object')
adding_var_inside_function(df)
print(df.columns) # Index([u'value'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Read [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html#mutability-and-copying-of-data). If you need an independent copy of your DF use this method: `df2 = df.copy()`

Comment: So adding a column is one of the only things that can change the global DataFrame??? Seems like mutability should be an all or nothing affair for a particular type of object absent an explicit declaration. They don't even list out the other attributes that are mutable! Nevertheless, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html#mutability-and-copying-of-data):

> **Mutability and copying of data**
>
> All pandas data structures are value-mutable (the values they contain can be altered) but not always
>   size-mutable. The length of a Series cannot be changed, but, for
>   example, columns can be inserted into a DataFrame. However, the vast
>   majority of methods produce new objects and leave the input data
>   untouched. In general, though, we like to **favor immutability** where
>   sensible.

Here is another example, showing values (cell's) mutability:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   a  b  c
0  3  2  0
1  3  3  1
2  4  0  0
3  2  3  2
4  0  4  4

In [22]: df2 = df

In [23]: df2.loc[0, 'a'] = 100

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
     a  b  c
0  100  2  0
1    3  3  1
2    4  0  0
3    2  3  2
4    0  4  4
```

`df2` is a reference to `df`

```
In [28]: id(df) == id(df2)
Out[28]: True
```

Your function, that won't mutate the argument DF:

```
def adding_var_inside_function(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['value'] = 0
    return df

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
     a  b  c
0  100  2  0
1    3  3  1
2    4  0  0
3    2  3  2
4    0  4  4

In [31]: adding_var_inside_function(df)
Out[31]:
     a  b  c  value
0  100  2  0      0
1    3  3  1      0
2    4  0  0      0
3    2  3  2      0
4    0  4  4      0

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
     a  b  c
0  100  2  0
1    3  3  1
2    4  0  0
3    2  3  2
4    0  4  4
```